# Harmful to plug earbuds into computers?

Tags: mac, audio, iphone, earbuds

I just purchased a pair of Bose QC20. Advertised as noise-canceling headphones, they are actually earbuds. I usually use them with my iPhone. My question is: is it harmful to the earbuds if I use them on a Mac or PC? Is it possible that the difference in voltage, output (not sure what that's called) between an iPhone and a laptop will harm the earbuds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn your volume down on your computer before you connect them the first time.  There is a small chance that if you have your volume maxed, and your sound card is able to provide a lot of power, then it could blow the speakers in your earbuds, along with damaging your hearing.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy headphones that come with 3.5mm jack it is designed to be used on all devices that have 3.5mm headphone jack.

Note: I would lower the sound on laptop before plugging the headphones just to make sure that you are not playing them at full blast causes problems to headphones and your ears.

Answer (score 0):

First, no.  There won't be any harm in plugging those headphones into your laptop.  Voltage tolerances are identical between the iphone and PCs.  What is not always identical is the type of plug.  The QC20 has a 4-conductor 3.5mm plug which includes ground, left, right and microphone channels.  Typical 3.5mm headphones for music & such only have 3-conductors (left, right and ground)  There should not be any problems using this, as the conductor used for the mic sits in what would normally be ground.  To be safe, or to gain full-functionality, I would  suggest investing in something like this:
[http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-MUYHSFMM-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B0058DOWH6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058DOWH6)

This splits the ear-phone connections and the microphone connections into 2 separate plugs.  The only down-side is that you won't be able to get any use out of the button.  (no way to detect button-press from a laptop)